# buildTypes.each String for API's in Android Gradle configuration

Tags: android

I'm working on Google's Udacity course for new Android Devs, and I've come into some trouble with the Gradle build and defining a constant in it. I've tried surrounding the field with multiple variations of ", ', and \'s that I say recommended online, but nothing seems to work. I was wondering how to format the line inside buildTypes.each, seen here?

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField "String", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", **APICodeHere**
}
```

Here's the entirety of the code for the app's gradle build.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField "String", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", **APICodeHere**
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 13):

I am also taking this course and I had the same problem. The formatting that eventually worked for me is this:

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "\"6df0...9ac\""
```

Paste your hexadecimal Open Weather API Key instead of the  `6df0...9ac`  above. Hope that helps!

Comment: After trying many different things this solution solved the issue for me! I wish they would mention this in the course.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle creates a BuildConfig file to store the variables created by itself like **VERSION_CODE**, **APPLICATION_ID**, and others.

So what you should have to do is to put the instruction `buildTypes.each{}` inside your app.gradle file to create some new variables you want to create there.

In your app.gradle file, your code should be like this:

```
 ...
buildTypes{ 
    release {
        bla bla bla 
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField("TYPE_OF_PARAM", "PARAM_NAME", "PARAM_VALUE")
    }
}
```

where

- TYPE_OF_PARAM is the type that you want to set to your "variable" (String, for example).
- PARAM_NAME is the name of your new created variable.
- PARAM_VALUE is the value that you want to set to your variable.

**IMPORTANT**

If you are setting a new String variable, you should use the `\"` to set the quotation marks to your new variable. So, if I'm setting a String, I should modify the PARAM_VALUE to `"\"My String\""`. This way, when gradle sets your String variable, it will set the quotation marks too.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it visible through github by calling it from within a folder you will open under the project package.

```
app.gradle:

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
        def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'youtubeapi',
                    keystoreProperties['YoutubeApi']
        }`
project.keystore.properties:
YoutubeApi="keykeykeykeykapikey";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution below code only worked for me

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URL', SERVER_URL
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'ENC_KEY', ENC_KEY
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', API_KEY
    }
```

Then Build->clean Project and Rebuild Project. After Rebuilt its started working.